# Whether it is possible to add redirect link in RAML file e.g. to another API version?

Tags: api, documentation, raml

As in subject, I have two RAMLs files one is related with v1 API version, second one is belongs to v2 API version. My problem is that, if I pass to someone my root url with API documentation I wan't to be sure that when someone enters into API v1 page he will be able to se some info ("This is old api version please go to API v2: link") and redirect link to API v2?

Is any way to put this redirect link into v1 RAML file?

Thank for any responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `documentation` section supports Markdown so you can easily insert a link there.

Answer (score 0):

yes You can add Direct URL if its not working then you can try bellow syntax as well

```
response:
  200:
    example:
      {
        "redirecturl":"URL Location"
      }
```